# Time based cross-validation for EOM patterns

Tags: time-series, python, forecasting, finance, moving-window

I want to evaluate different models (ARIMA, MLP, LSTM, regression, etc.) on their performance to predict/forecast stock prices in a period (horizon) of 7 days around month-end. The data for these stock prices is also non-stationary, so considering doing the forecast on the differenced price series. I have data on a multitude of features (170 variables ranging from bond spreads to economic indicators) covering several years.

But my problem is choosing how to make the forecasts, especially for the seven-day period around the end-of-month close (from three days before to three days after). There are surges in prices and increases in volatility within this seven day period, so not really sure if this is like a "mini-seasonality" or just anomalies, and how to handle this.

I have tried to use the window approach for cross validation, but this does not consider the "time placement" of the data. **So does anyone have any thoughts on boosting forecasting performance and making it forecast a seven-day period around month-end (and not random 7 days irrespective of when in the month)?**